# Possible Bug when using diff on datetime objects in a pandas groupby object with multiindex

Tags: python, pandas, types

Consider a dataframe with a column with labels that are used to create groups and two rows of the same dates:

```
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd

dd = [['A','A','A','A','B','B']\
     ,[dt.date(1981,3,6),dt.date(1986,5,1),dt.date(1983,11,8)\
     ,dt.date(1982,6,11),dt.date(1977,2,26),dt.date(1991,9,4)]]
dd = map(list,zip(*dd))
DF = pd.DataFrame(dd,columns=['Label','Date'])
DF['Date2'] = DF['Date'].copy()

print DF
print type(DF.Date[0])
print type(DF.Date2[0])
```

This yields:

```
  Label        Date       Date2
0     A  1981-03-06  1981-03-06
1     A  1986-05-01  1986-05-01
2     A  1983-11-08  1983-11-08
3     A  1982-06-11  1982-06-11
4     B  1977-02-26  1977-02-26
5     B  1991-09-04  1991-09-04
<type 'datetime.date'>
<type 'datetime.date'>
```

Now I can do these:

```
print DF.groupby(['Label']).diff()
print "======================================"
print DF.groupby(['Label']).apply(lambda s: s[u'Date'].diff())
print "======================================"
print DF.groupby(['Label']).apply(lambda s: s[u'Date2'].diff())
```

Leading to this output:

```
                 Date               Date2
0                 NaN                 NaN
1  1882 days, 0:00:00  1882 days, 0:00:00
2  -905 days, 0:00:00  -905 days, 0:00:00
3  -515 days, 0:00:00  -515 days, 0:00:00
4                 NaN                 NaN
5  5303 days, 0:00:00  5303 days, 0:00:00
======================================
Label   
A      0         NaT
       1   1882 days
       2   -905 days
       3   -515 days
B      4         NaT
       5   5303 days
Name: Date, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
======================================
Label   
A      0         NaT
       1   1882 days
       2   -905 days
       3   -515 days
B      4         NaT
       5   5303 days
Name: Date2, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

However when I'm doing these:

```
print DF.groupby(['Label','Date']).diff()
print "======================================"
print DF.groupby(['Label','Date']).apply(lambda s: s[u'Date2'].diff())
print "======================================"
print DF.groupby(['Label','Date'])[u'Date2'].transform(pd.Series.diff)
```

Then the output is broken:

```
  Date2
0   NaN
1   NaN
2   NaN
3   NaN
4   NaN
5   NaN
======================================
Label  Date         
A      1981-03-06  0    NaN
       1982-06-11  3    NaN
       1983-11-08  2    NaN
       1986-05-01  1    NaN
B      1977-02-26  4    NaN
       1991-09-04  5    NaN
Name: Date2, dtype: object
======================================
0    NaN
1    NaN
2    NaN
3    NaN
4    NaN
5    NaN
Name: Date2, dtype: object
```

As you can see for some reason the Date2 column is no longer a timedelta64 dtype but just an object type. This happens with every method I have tried and also when switching the two date columns, so this must be something to do with the multiindex groupby.

I can't tell if this is expected or unexpected behaviour, that is if it's a bug or not.

EDIT: Pandas 0.18.1 on Python 2.7.12

EDIT2: Deleted, my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two problems - first you need dtypes `datetimes` and then your sample data where output is `NaT` (len of each group was `1`, so `difference` is `NaT`):

```
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd

dd = [['A','A','A','A','B','B']\
     ,[dt.date(1981,3,6),dt.date(1986,5,1),dt.date(1983,11,8)\
     ,dt.date(1982,6,11),dt.date(1977,2,26),dt.date(1991,9,4)]]
dd = list(zip(*dd))
DF = pd.DataFrame(dd,columns=['Label','Date'])
DF['Date2'] = DF['Date'].copy()

print (DF)
  Label        Date       Date2
0     A  1981-03-06  1981-03-06
1     A  1986-05-01  1986-05-01
2     A  1983-11-08  1983-11-08
3     A  1982-06-11  1982-06-11
4     B  1977-02-26  1977-02-26
5     B  1991-09-04  1991-09-04
```

```
print (DF.dtypes)
Label    object
Date     object
Date2    object
dtype: object

DF['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(DF['Date'])
DF['Date2'] = pd.to_datetime(DF['Date2'])
print (DF.dtypes)
Label            object
Date     datetime64[ns]
Date2    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object

print (DF.groupby(['Label','Date'])['Date2'].diff())
0   NaT
1   NaT
2   NaT
3   NaT
4   NaT
5   NaT
Name: Date2, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

I changed data in `Date2`:

```
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd

dd = [['A','A','A','A','B','B']\
     ,[dt.date(1981,3,6),dt.date(1981,3,6),dt.date(1983,11,8)\
     ,dt.date(1983,11,8),dt.date(1977,2,26),dt.date(1991,9,4)]\
     ,[dt.date(1981,3,6),dt.date(1986,5,1),dt.date(1983,11,8)\
         ,dt.date(1982,6,11),dt.date(1977,2,26),dt.date(1991,9,4)]]
dd = list(zip(*dd))
DF = pd.DataFrame(dd,columns=['Label','Date', 'Date2'])

DF['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(DF['Date'])
DF['Date2'] = pd.to_datetime(DF['Date2'])
print (DF)
  Label       Date      Date2
0     A 1981-03-06 1981-03-06
1     A 1981-03-06 1986-05-01
2     A 1983-11-08 1983-11-08
3     A 1983-11-08 1982-06-11
4     B 1977-02-26 1977-02-26
5     B 1991-09-04 1991-09-04

print (DF.dtypes)
Label            object
Date     datetime64[ns]
Date2    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

```
print (DF.groupby(['Label','Date'])['Date2'].diff())
0         NaT
1   1882 days
2         NaT
3   -515 days
4         NaT
5         NaT
Name: Date2, dtype: timedelta64[ns]

print (DF.groupby(['Label','Date']).diff())
      Date2
0       NaT
1 1882 days
2       NaT
3 -515 days
4       NaT
5       NaT
Label  Date  
print (DF.groupby(['Label','Date']).apply(lambda s: s[u'Date2'].diff()))
A      1981-03-06  0         NaT
                   1   1882 days
       1983-11-08  2         NaT
                   3   -515 days
B      1977-02-26  4         NaT
       1991-09-04  5         NaT
Name: Date2, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
print (DF.groupby(['Label','Date'])[u'Date2'].transform(pd.Series.diff))
0          NaT
1   1975-02-26
2          NaT
3   1968-08-04
4          NaT
5          NaT
Name: Date2, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

If remove converting [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html), output is `NaN` and with groups with numbers `NaT`:

```
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd

dd = [['A','A','A','A','B','B']\
     ,[dt.date(1981,3,6),dt.date(1981,3,6),dt.date(1983,11,8)\
     ,dt.date(1983,11,8),dt.date(1977,2,26),dt.date(1991,9,4)]\
     ,[dt.date(1981,3,6),dt.date(1986,5,1),dt.date(1983,11,8)\
         ,dt.date(1982,6,11),dt.date(1977,2,26),dt.date(1991,9,4)]]
dd = list(zip(*dd))
DF = pd.DataFrame(dd,columns=['Label','Date', 'Date2'])
print (DF)
  Label        Date       Date2
0     A  1981-03-06  1981-03-06
1     A  1981-03-06  1986-05-01
2     A  1983-11-08  1983-11-08
3     A  1983-11-08  1982-06-11
4     B  1977-02-26  1977-02-26
5     B  1991-09-04  1991-09-04

print (DF.dtypes)
Label    object
Date     object
Date2    object
dtype: object
```

```
print (DF.groupby(['Label','Date'])['Date2'].diff())
0                   NaT
1    1882 days, 0:00:00
2                   NaT
3    -515 days, 0:00:00
4                   NaN
5                   NaN
Name: Date2, dtype: object

print (DF.groupby(['Label','Date']).diff())
                Date2
0                 NaN
1  1882 days, 0:00:00
2                 NaN
3  -515 days, 0:00:00
4                 NaN
5                 NaN
print (DF.groupby(['Label','Date']).apply(lambda s: s[u'Date2'].diff()))
Label  Date         
A      1981-03-06  0                   NaT
                   1    1882 days, 0:00:00
       1983-11-08  2                   NaT
                   3    -515 days, 0:00:00
B      1977-02-26  4                   NaN
       1991-09-04  5                   NaN
Name: Date2, dtype: object
print (DF.groupby(['Label','Date'])[u'Date2'].transform(pd.Series.diff))
0                  None
1    162604800000000000
2                  None
3    -44496000000000000
4                   NaN
5                   NaN
Name: Date2, dtype: object
```

EDIT:

If length of group is `1` and it means has one row, then [`diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.diff.html) return `NaT`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import io

import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd

dd = [['A','A','A','A','B','B']\
     ,[dt.date(1981,3,6),dt.date(1981,3,6),dt.date(1983,11,8)\
     ,dt.date(1983,11,8),dt.date(1977,2,26),dt.date(1991,9,4)]\
     ,[dt.date(1981,3,6),dt.date(1986,5,1),dt.date(1983,11,8)\
     ,dt.date(1982,6,11),dt.date(1977,2,26),dt.date(1991,9,4)]]

dd = list(zip(*dd))
DF = pd.DataFrame(dd,columns=['Label','Date', 'Date2'])
DF['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(DF['Date'])
DF['Date2'] = pd.to_datetime(DF['Date2'])
print (DF)
  Label       Date      Date2
0     A 1981-03-06 1981-03-06
1     A 1981-03-06 1986-05-01
2     A 1983-11-08 1983-11-08
3     A 1983-11-08 1982-06-11
4     B 1977-02-26 1977-02-26
5     B 1991-09-04 1991-09-04
```

```
for i, g in DF.groupby(['Label','Date']):
    print (g)
    print ('diff: ')
    print (g[['Date', 'Date2']].diff())
    print ('------------')

0     A 1981-03-06 1981-03-06
1     A 1981-03-06 1986-05-01
diff: 
    Date     Date2
0    NaT       NaT
1 0 days 1882 days
------------
  Label       Date      Date2
2     A 1983-11-08 1983-11-08
3     A 1983-11-08 1982-06-11
diff: 
    Date     Date2
2    NaT       NaT
3 0 days -515 days
------------
  Label       Date      Date2
4     B 1977-02-26 1977-02-26
diff: 
   Date  Date2
4   NaT    NaT
------------
  Label       Date      Date2
5     B 1991-09-04 1991-09-04
diff: 
   Date  Date2
5   NaT    NaT
------------
print ('*************************')
```

```
for i, g in DF.groupby(['Label','Date2']):
    print (g)
    print ('diff2: ')
    print (g[['Date', 'Date2']].diff())
    print ('------------')

  Label       Date      Date2
0     A 1981-03-06 1981-03-06
diff2: 
   Date  Date2
0   NaT    NaT
------------
  Label       Date      Date2
3     A 1983-11-08 1982-06-11
diff2: 
   Date  Date2
3   NaT    NaT
------------
  Label       Date      Date2
2     A 1983-11-08 1983-11-08
diff2: 
   Date  Date2
2   NaT    NaT
------------
  Label       Date      Date2
1     A 1981-03-06 1986-05-01
diff2: 
   Date  Date2
1   NaT    NaT
------------
  Label       Date      Date2
4     B 1977-02-26 1977-02-26
diff2: 
   Date  Date2
4   NaT    NaT
------------
  Label       Date      Date2
5     B 1991-09-04 1991-09-04
diff2: 
   Date  Date2
5   NaT    NaT
------------
```

Comment: So I need to manually transform dates from datetime.date to datetime64?

Comment: hmmm it seems you have output object, where each object is datetime. But it works, if dtypes of column is not object, but `datetime64[ns]`.

Comment: Hmmm, I test it again and if remove converting to `to_datetime`, it works too, but output is sometimes `NaN` and sometimes `NaT`.

Comment: Yeah, using `to_datetime` doesn't lead to `NaN`. Your answer did help me, although the behaviour is still odd, see my last edit.

Comment: Disregard that, I made a mistake and already deleted that edit.

Comment: I think it is correct, becasue if changed Dates, each group has only one row, so always output of `diff` is `NaT`.

Comment: No problem, I only changed in groupby `Date` to `Date2`, so I think now it is more clear.